# Remove Unlock Pattern in Motorola Razr i?

Tags: motorola-droid-razr, pattern-lock

I bought a Motorola Razr i in the web but It turns out that the phone has an unlock pattern and now I can't contact the seller. I have read some tutorials of the web talking about the "Hard Reset" which consist in something like this:

http://www.smartmobilephonesolutions.com/content/how-to-hard-reset-an-android-phone

When I try to do it I never see the Menu that I souposed to.

I really dont know If im doing well the process so I need someone to help me with specific instrucions of how to do this or with another solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried it on my Motorola Razr i (4.1.2 Retail en GB):
To get into fastboot menu.

1. Turn off device.
2. Hold "Down Volume Button" (for a few seconds) and
       then "Power Button"
3. When phone vibrates/Motorola logo shows up/Green light goes off
       release "Power Button" but continue to hold "Down Volume Button"
4. Device will enter fastboot menu.

It did take a few tries to get the timing right.

Answer (score 0):

hard reset: press vol down + power for 20 seconds. the device will start to boot and you can release the buttons. this probably won't clear the unlock pattern. to clear the unlock pattern you'll want to do a factory reset.

factory reset:

- power off device.
- press and hold vol down + power until you see the **BOOT OPTIONS** screen.
- press vol down until **RECOVERY** is highlighted, then press power to select.
- when the screen shows an android on its back with an exclamation point, press and hold vol down for 5-10 seconds then tap vol up while still holding vol down. the screen should now display the recovery mode menu.
- press vol down until **Wipe user data/factory reset** is highlighted, then press power to select.
- press vol down until **Yes - delete all user data** is highlighted and press power to select.
- the device will wipe and format the data and cache partitions. when that's done, press power to select the **Reboot** option.

the device should boot into initial setup and you'll have a fresh razr to play with and no pattern lock.

[motorola help article](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/71984)